# Two integral domains with isomorphic field of fractions aren't necessarily isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I "proved" a false result: that if the field of fractions are isomorphic then so are the underlying integral domains. I'd like feedback on where I messed up in the following proof.

Let $R_1, R_2$ be integral domains with isomorphic fields of fractions. That is,
$$
R_1 \times R_1 - \{0\} \cong R_2 \times R_2 - \{0\}  
$$
Then, the subgroups $R_1 \times \{1\}$ and $R_2\times\{1\}$ are isomorphic.

Now, we show that these subgroups are isomorphic to $R_1$ and $R_2$, respectively.
Let $\phi: R_1\to R_1\times\{1\}$ be the homomorphism
$$
\phi(\alpha) \to (\alpha, 1).
$$
It's surjective, since for $(\beta, 1)\in R_1\times\{1\}$, we have $\phi(\beta) = (\beta, 1)$.

It's injective, since assume that $\phi(\alpha) = \phi(\beta)$. Thus, $(\alpha, 1) = (\beta, 1)$. By the equivalence relation on the field of fractions, $\alpha\cdot 1 = \beta\cdot1$. Hence, $\alpha = \beta$.

Now, to prove it's a homomorphism, we see that $\phi(1) = (1, 1)$.

Further,
$$
\phi(\alpha + \beta) = (\alpha + \beta, 1) = (\alpha, 1) + (\beta, 1) = \phi(\alpha) + \phi(\beta)
$$
and
$$
\phi(\alpha\cdot\beta) = (\alpha\cdot\beta, 1) = (\alpha, 1)\cdot(\beta, 1) = \phi(\alpha)\cdot\phi(\beta)
$$

Thus, we have
$$
R_1 \cong R_1 \times \{1\} \cong R_2\times\{1\} \cong R_2
$$
and therefore
$$
R_1\cong R_2
$$

Comment: "The subgroups $R_1\times\{1\}$ and $R_2\times\{1\}$ are isomorphic" is false. E.g., $R_1=\mathbb Z$, $R_2=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Your "That is" reformulation is not correct. The field of fractions is not just two copies of the ring (there is also an equivalence relation to be added).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Could you kindly furnish that as a solution, please? Although it seems a simple thing to report on, that is the heart of the problem encountered, and it resolves the perceived contradiction the user was facing.